# SQL - How to add a custom text at the beginng of a row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i have a sql query to merge all rows to one.

What i try to is to set only a custom at the beginning.

My problem is that always repeat it for every new value.

How can i fix it?

Thanks in advance

here is my code:

```
SELECT 
   STUFF ((SELECT 'Please Select' + ' : ' + Name
          FROM Option
          ORDER BY Name
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') MergeResult
```

My result i need is like this:

Please Select: Option1 - Option2 - Option3 etc........

What i get at this moment are this:

Please Select: Option1 - Please Select: Option2 - Please Select: Option3

Comment: This is Microsoft, not MySQL - right?

Comment: Just move `'Please Select' + ' : ' +` from inner query to before `STUFF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

Move the Select to the outside:

```
DECLARE @Option AS TABLE ([Name] varchar(30))
INSERT INTO @Option([Name])
VALUES ('Option1'), ('Option2'), ('Option3')


SELECT 'Please Select : ' + LEFT(Options, LEN(Options) - 2)
FROM 
(
    SELECT Name + ' - '
    FROM @Option
    ORDER BY Name
    FOR XML PATH('')
) o (Options)
```

There is also the COALESCE way:

```
DECLARE @Option AS TABLE ([Name] varchar(30))
INSERT INTO @Option([Name])
VALUES ('Option1'), ('Option2'), ('Option3')

DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ' - ', '') + Name 
FROM @Option
SELECT 'Please Select : ' + @Names
```

Comment: yep.your are right.. its working... hehe. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```
SELECT 
    'Please Select' + ' : ' + 
    STUFF ((SELECT Name
          FROM [Option]
          ORDER BY Name
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') MergeResult
```

I.e., move the prefix to the outside